# Gitlab CE - Master can edit anyone else's comments - can this be changed?

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab CE, Master has permissions to edit anyone everyones commit comments. Shouldn't Owner's be the only one with this level of access?

Is there a setting to allow us to change comment editing from Master to Owner?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting proposal. Maybe only owners and admins should be able to do this. Anyway, GitLab does show when a comment was edited.

Comment: I think proposal makes sense. Only project owners and admins should be able to edit everyones comment.

Comment: Cool, please contribute this!

Comment: Super, thanks! As a temporary fix, we've had to move all users back to DEVELOPER.